# How to align Select element right after photo

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on some price calculator, but I'm currently having problems with aligning  input, I want to align it right after image like on this website for example:

[image]

I was trying to add padding but it will just add white space, not what I want to do. Here is what I have right now:

[image]

My code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #00132b;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.boost-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.boost-tab a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.boost-tab a:hover: {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.boost-tab a.active {
  background-color: #0750ab;
  color: white;
}

.tab-center {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .boost-tab a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.current-rank h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 178px;
}

.current-rank select {
  text-align: top;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="boost-tab">
  <div class="tab-center">
    <a class="active" href="#division">Division</a>
    <a href="#netwin">Netwin</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="current-rank">
  <fieldset>
    <h1>Current rank</h1>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/t2SI1Ts.png" style="width: 240px; height: 170px; padding-left: 80px;">
    <select id="division">
      <option value="1">Iron</option>
      <option value="2">Bronze</option>
      <option value="3">Silver</option>
      <option value="4">Gold</option>
      <option value="5">Platinum</option>
      <option value="6">Diamond</option>
      <option value="7">MASTER</option>
    </select>
    <select id="division">
      <option value="1">DIVISION IV</option>
      <option value="2">DIVISION III</option>
      <option value="3">DIVISION II</option>
      <option value="4">DIVISION I</option>
    </select>
    <select id="division">
      <option value="1">0-20 LP</option>
      <option value="2">21-40 LP</option>
      <option value="3">41-60</option>
      <option value="4">61-80</option>
      <option value="5">81-100</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to do so... Like this:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #00132b;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.boost-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.boost-tab a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.boost-tab a:hover: {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.boost-tab a.active {
  background-color: #0750ab;
  color: white;
}

.tab-center {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .boost-tab a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.current-rank h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 178px;
}

.current-rank select {
  text-align: top;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-2 select {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boost-tab">
  <div class="tab-center">
    <a class="active" href="#division">Division</a>
    <a href="#netwin">Netwin</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="current-rank">
  <fieldset>
    <h1>Current rank</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/t2SI1Ts.png" style="width: 240px; height: 170px; padding-left: 80px;">
      </div>

      <div class="col-2">
        <select id="division">
          <option value="1">Iron</option>
          <option value="2">Bronze</option>
          <option value="3">Silver</option>
          <option value="4">Gold</option>
          <option value="5">Platinum</option>
          <option value="6">Diamond</option>
          <option value="7">MASTER</option>
        </select>
        <select id="division">
          <option value="1">DIVISION IV</option>
          <option value="2">DIVISION III</option>
          <option value="3">DIVISION II</option>
          <option value="4">DIVISION I</option>
        </select>
        <select id="division">
          <option value="1">0-20 LP</option>
          <option value="2">21-40 LP</option>
          <option value="3">41-60</option>
          <option value="4">61-80</option>
          <option value="5">81-100</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your css code:

```
.listIn{
list-style:none;
float:right;}
.listIn li{
    margin:10px 0;}
```

html code:

```
<div class="boost-tab">
<div class="tab-center">
<a class="active" href="#division">Division</a>
<a href="#netwin">Netwin</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="current-rank">
<fieldset>
<h1>Current rank</h1>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/t2SI1Ts.png" style="width: 240px; height: 170px; 
 padding-left: 80px;">
<ul class="listIn">
<li>
<select id="division">
  <option value="1">Iron</option>
  <option value="2">Bronze</option>
  <option value="3">Silver</option>
  <option value="4">Gold</option>
  <option value="5">Platinum</option>
  <option value="6">Diamond</option>
  <option value="7">MASTER</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>
<select id="division">
  <option value="1">DIVISION IV</option>
  <option value="2">DIVISION III</option>
  <option value="3">DIVISION II</option>
  <option value="4">DIVISION I</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>
<select id="division">
  <option value="1">0-20 LP</option>
  <option value="2">21-40 LP</option>
  <option value="3">41-60</option>
  <option value="4">61-80</option>
  <option value="5">81-100</option>
</select>
</li>
 </fieldset>
  </div>
```

use Bootstrap will make it easier for you

Answer (score 0):

- you can use a [flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) it can help you in this
- You not allow to set the same id for multiple element in your html  so `id="division"` wrong

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #00132b;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.boost-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.boost-tab a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.boost-tab a:hover: {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.boost-tab a.active {
  background-color: #0750ab;
  color: white;
}

.tab-center {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .boost-tab a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.current-rank h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 178px;
}

.current-rank select {
  text-align: top;
  width:200px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img-option-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  }
  
.options{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
 }
```

```html
<div class="boost-tab">
  <div class="tab-center">
    <a class="active" href="#division">Division</a>
    <a href="#netwin">Netwin</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="current-rank">
  <fieldset>
    <h1>Current rank</h1>
    <div class="img-option-container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/t2SI1Ts.png" style="width: 240px; height: 170px; padding-left: 80px;">
    <div class="options">
    <select class="division">
      <option value="1">Iron</option>
      <option value="2">Bronze</option>
      <option value="3">Silver</option>
      <option value="4">Gold</option>
      <option value="5">Platinum</option>
      <option value="6">Diamond</option>
      <option value="7">MASTER</option>
    </select>
    <select class="division">
      <option value="1">DIVISION IV</option>
      <option value="2">DIVISION III</option>
      <option value="3">DIVISION II</option>
      <option value="4">DIVISION I</option>
    </select>
    <select class="division">
      <option value="1">0-20 LP</option>
      <option value="2">21-40 LP</option>
      <option value="3">41-60</option>
      <option value="4">61-80</option>
      <option value="5">81-100</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some tags in your html.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #00132b;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.boost-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.boost-tab a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.boost-tab a:hover: {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.boost-tab a.active {
  background-color: #0750ab;
  color: white;
}

.tab-center {
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .boost-tab a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.current-rank h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 178px;
}

.current-rank select {
  text-align: top;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
}

.left-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.right-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boost-tab">
  <div class="tab-center">
    <a class="active" href="#division">Division</a>
    <a href="#netwin">Netwin</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="current-rank">
  <fieldset>
    <h1>Current rank</h1>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="left-section">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/t2SI1Ts.png" style="width: 240px; height: 170px; padding-left: 80px;">
      </div>
      <div class="right-section">
        <select id="division">
          <option value="1">Iron</option>
          <option value="2">Bronze</option>
          <option value="3">Silver</option>
          <option value="4">Gold</option>
          <option value="5">Platinum</option>
          <option value="6">Diamond</option>
          <option value="7">MASTER</option>
        </select>
        <select id="division">
          <option value="1">DIVISION IV</option>
          <option value="2">DIVISION III</option>
          <option value="3">DIVISION II</option>
          <option value="4">DIVISION I</option>
        </select>
        <select id="division">
          <option value="1">0-20 LP</option>
          <option value="2">21-40 LP</option>
          <option value="3">41-60</option>
          <option value="4">61-80</option>
          <option value="5">81-100</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```